# How to add custom column index based on date

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have data as such:

[image]

I want to split the data in the following format based on date. So going forward the dates can be split and I can use slicer to select the range and get the index value over each selected dates.

[image]

Please help on this.

Comment: Your pivoted result does not make sense. The first row for example, combines rows #1 and #8 from your table, but there is a prefix `17/22/38` in row #8 which makes the URL different than the one from row #1. Where did this prefix go? How it disappeared and why? And this is also for the other rows, e.g. `Contact-us`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pivoted result does not make sense. The first row for example, combines rows #1 and #8 from your table, but there is a prefix `17/22/38` in row #8 which makes the URL different than the one from row #1. Where did this prefix go? How it disappeared and why? And this is also for the other rows, e.g. `Contact-us`.

But otherwise, [Pivot columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-common-query-tasks#pivot-columns) is what you need. If your original table looks like this:

[image]

Select `Date` column and click `Pivot column` command in the ribbon, and you will get a dialog like this:

[image]

Select `Index` as values column. In you case probably it makes no sense to aggregate indexes, so select `Don't Aggregate`. This will give you a result like this:

[image]

Which is as close to your desired result, as possible (considering the issue that I mentioned above).

And here is the M code to reproduce the steps above:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("hdE9CoAwDIDRq0jmUpL0z55FOujsJAge36CQycSl3/IgJF0WoB6xR0bqEGDdLnnPY59ISjCCCViaPJCk7IEszR4o0uKBKm0eaNL6AMZPMOsIA3Rd0wCEfzOIdFFLsN7KEkn/wxL5Pca4AQ==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Date = _t, Search_Term = _t, Url = _t, Index = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type date}, {"Search_Term", type text}, {"Url", type text}, {"Index", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Changed Type", {{"Date", type text}}, "en-US"), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Changed Type", {{"Date", type text}}, "en-US")[Date]), "Date", "Index")
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

Comment: Thanks. I know the data doesn't make that much of sense. I had to filter out the rows with dates in the `Url` so that it would make some sense.